# What is the meaning of "provider" and "uid" in the Devise user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I don't understand what are "provider" and "uid" in the user table generated by Devise. Please, help me!

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: Short for "user_id"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Devise support OmniAuth integration by default.

In order to do so it creates two extra column `provider` and `uid` where provider consist oAuth provider i.e facebook, google, linkedin etc. and uid will consist unique id of the user who logged in using oAuth.